# Does an errata negating the Lame Oracle's 5th level benefit exist?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, errata, oracle

I was under the impression that the Lame Oracle curse was errataed to no longer grant immunity to self imposed fatigue effects. Does that errata exist or was I misinformed? I can't find the errata anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No errata for that exists, you were misinformed

The ability confers immunity to fatigue at fifth level, and to exhaustion later.  No exception is given for self-imposed effects, and no errata to that effect is present (c.f. e.g. the description in the PRD, which contains the following ['we contain all official errata' page](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/updates.html), and the [official errata to the APG](http://paizo.com/download/pathfinder/AdvancedPlayersGuideErrata1_0.zip), and [the Paizo forums](http://paizo.com/search?q=lame+Oracle&forum=v5748dmtz1gek)).